# db.[table].Add(obj) cannot convert. Error Code CS1503

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

I am getting an error on my ASP.Net MVC 5 App in my UserController.cs file. The error I get is `CS1503` but the reason doesn't make sense compared to others issues/resolutions.

The full error is:

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Elevate_Your_Pitch.Models.tblRegistration' to Elevate_Your_Pitch.Models.user' on line 25

I will have the code for my `UserController.cs` (controller) , `tblRegistration.cs` (model) and `Registration.Context.cs` (edmx) files below:

**UserController.cs**

```
using System;
using Stystem.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.MVC;
using Elevate_Your_Pitch.Models;

namespace Elevate_Your_Pitch.Controllers
{
  public class UserController : Controller
  {
    // Get: User
    public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(tblRegistration obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            elevate_your_pitchEntities db = new elevate_your_pitchEntities();
            db.users.Add(obj); //This is line 25 and (obj) is causing the error
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(obj);
    }
  }


}
```

**Registration.Context.cs**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Elevate_Your_Pitch.Models
{
  using System;
  using System.Data.Entity;
  using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

  public partial class elevatey_your_pitchEntities : DbContext
  {
       public elevatey_your_pitchEntities() : base("name=elevatey_your_pitchEntities")
       {
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
          throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
       }

       public virtual DbSet<user> users { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**tblRegistrations.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Elevate_Your_Pitch.Models
{
  [Table("user")]
  public partial class tblRegistration
  {
      [Key]
      public int UserID { get; set;  }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public string EmailID { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
      public string Password { get; set; }
      public string IsEmailVerified { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? It doesn't make sense.

**UPDATE**

**View**

Located in Views/User
**Index.cshtml**

```
@model Elevate_Your_Pitch.Models.tblRegistration

@{
  Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
          <h4>tblRegistration</h4>
          <hr />
          @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          <div class="form-group">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
              <div class="col-md-10">
                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
              <div class="col-md-10">
                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
              <div class="col-md-10">
                  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
              <div class="col-md-10">
                  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
              <div class="col-md-10">
                  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsEmailVerified, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
              <div class="col-md-10">
                  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsEmailVerified, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsEmailVerified, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                  <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    }

    <div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried deleting the class from the designer then adding it back in (from db )?

Comment: you may want to show us the model for User

Comment: @JohnB I have added the view to the question. Let me know if you see something I did stupidly.

Comment: @JohnB I haven't tried that yet but that was going to be my next step, I just wanted to know what I did wrong.

Comment: @JohnB I ended up getting it to work, something in the database was broke so once I rebuilt that and rebuilt the project it worked perfectly, thanks for your help, if you add that as an answer, ill mark it for ya.

Answer (score 0):

For me I solved this error , I found 2 class with the same name Registration class I changed one and keep one class name Registration and its worked .